# Tomcat two projects communicate each other

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, pentaho

currently I was working on pentaho and jsp projects my jsp wroject name as web and for that I used `tomcat 7`. I run pentaho in my running tomcat so in my tomcat webapps contains two folder name like web and pentaho. For pentaho I configured `context.xml` in `META-INF` and `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder using pentaho I was created report and used that report in `iframe` in my web project.
  Now my problem is that first user only see web project http://www.mydomain.com:8080/web using web project I want to access pentaho context xml properties using following code

```
 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

        // Look up our data source
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)
          envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
        System.out.println("Connections " + ds.getConnection());
```

how I can access pentaho context.xml file JNDI resources in my web project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your JNDI resources using the [GlobalNamingResources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Global_configuration) settings, otherwise the resource can only be accessed within a single application.

So probably moving the pentaho jndi section to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml would solve your problem.